# when does the Map return null?

Tags: map, collection, null, hashcode

```
class MapTask {
  
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    
      Map<KeyClass, Object> map = new HashMap<>();
      
      KeyClass key = new KeyClass();
      Object value = new Object();
      
      map.put(key, value);
      
      map.get(key); // this line should return null     
  }
  
}

class KeyClass {

  //class fields

}
```

The key is present and the value is not null
does it relate to implementing equals() method?

Comment: Hi Vlad, If you are working in Java, this is the wrong place to ask.

Comment: Why would you expect to return null, having set a value?

Comment: When you do this: `Object value = new Object();` you have initialized an object which has a memory address. Thus when you do `map.get(key)` you get the instance of the object.

Answer (score 1):

When using custom classes to define keys, you need both an `equals()` method and a `hashCode()` method in order to ensure that the key can be found. The latter identifies the correct "bucket" in which to find the key, and the former is used to ensure that the two objects are indeed equal.